# Удаление тэгов при сохранении страницы

Tags: php, html

Значит есть данные из MySQL. PHP файликом вывожу их. Так вот при "сохранении как" в файле появляются html тэги. Как убрать их, оставив только данные ?

Вот код в php файле:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) AS ts, value FROM sensor1") or die ("Query error");
$V0  = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$V0 .= sprintf( ' %u %f', $row['ts'], $row['value']);
}
mysql_close($con);
echo printf( '%s', strip_tags($V0));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `echo '----'; var_dump($V0)` что выводит?

Comment: @Naumov ----string(333354), а потом данные в двойных кавычках.

Comment: скрин сделай может html выводит не `sprint_f`

Answer (score 1):

Ваш браузер, скорее всего Google Chrome, при нажатии на кнопку "сохранить как" автоматический генерирует html разметку, даже если ее не прислал сервер, такова особенность работы данной функции, интерпретатор PHP тут не причем.

Для правильного сохранения данных воспользуйтесь просмотром исходного кода страницы в браузере или программными средствами позволяющие выполнять сохранение исходного кода без изменений (например CURL):

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost/mypage'
```

И вообще, зачем сохранять браузером с помощью "сохранить как", когда можно например отдавать готовый файл через этот же скрипт? Реализуйте сохранение файла например через file_put_contents по какому-то пути или отдавайте его сразу.